# What is the major product in the following reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, halogenation

**Reaction:**

> [image]

**My thought-process:**

According to me, this reaction is like the [bromination of alkene](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/03/15/alkene-bromination-mechanism/) but here instead of $\ce{CCl4}$ solvent, we have $\ce{H2O}$ as a solvent. For the first step a $3$-Membered Chlorinium Ion Intermediate is formed:

[image]

Now how do I proceed further? The solvent is $\ce{H2O}$ so it cannot act as a good nuclophile, whereas we still have the Cl- ion as a nucleophile available, so why doesn't the reaction proceed just like it would in $\ce{CCl4}$ medium, giving us a vicinal dichloride product.

According to the solution I have, a carbocation (the more stable out of the two possible carbocations) is formed and then $\ce{H2O}$ acts as a nucleophile  and according to that the product is formed. But can a carbocation form when the intermediate is a 3 membered halonium ion? I don't know about this. I'm confused, isn't this a SN$1$ type reaction, so how can a carbocation form?

The answer given is:

[image]

**P.S:** This question was asked in JEE Mains $12$ April $2019$ Shift $1$

Comment: You underestimate how good a nucleophile water is.

Comment: @Waylander Negatively charged species are better nucleophile than neutral species. In this case, we have bromide ion, so comparitively, isn't water a not so good nucleophile here?

Comment: You are incorrect about how good a nucleophile Chloride ion is, and there is far more water present than chloride.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the chloronium ion, you can think of it as having either of two carbocation structures, which are formed by breaking one or the other carbon-chlorine bond. Whichever carbocation is more stable forms with lower activation energy, so the nucleophile (water) will preferentially attack that carbocation center.

Here, if you break the carbon-chlorine bond on the right a primary carbocation is formed, whereas breaking the left bond gives a secondary cation. The secondary cation is more stable, so the water is directed accordingly.

Comment: Part of my question is why does bromide ion not attack? Is it becuase water is present in large quantity as compared to bromide ion?

Comment: If you mean chlorine (rather than bromine), yes - assuming you are using chlorine water for the reaction there is *much* more water than chlorine.